# jQuery Wrap a div from H2 until last paragraph

Tags: jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

I want to wrap a `<div>` FROM THE BEGINNING of the `<H2>` up until the next `<H2>`, but it is only starting on the first paragraph.

This is what I have, which ALMOST does the job:

```
$('h2:contains("test")').nextUntil('h2').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" />');
```

Here's my HTML:

```
/* from here */
<h2 class='test'>Include this in the wrap</h2>
<p>this</p>
<p>and this</p>
<p>and this</p> /* to here */

<h2 class='next'>before this</h2>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try:

```
$("h2.test").nextUntil("h2").andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" />');
```

[It does seem to do the trick.](http://jsfiddle.net/9xhET/)

Comment: @SparrwHawk - David Eddings! Ugh! Anyway, no problem, any time :)

Comment: David Eddings? Don't you mean Ursula Le Guin? :-P

Comment: @SparrHawk - I just remember a character called "Sparhawk" by the fantasy novelist David Eddings. I wasn't impressed by the character name, so I "judged the book by its cover" so to speak. But having spent ten seconds googling, I realised that I'm complaining about something unrelated altogether :)